# Steam Python get friend's state

Tags: python, steam

I'm using this module to interract with steam https://github.com/ValvePython/steam
But i can't get the right steam persona state, using this code

```
from steam import SteamClient
from steam.client.builtins.friends import *


client = SteamClient()


client.cli_login(username="username", password="password")  

sha = SteamUser(steam_id=77777777777777777, steam=client)

print(sha)
```

I get - `<SteamUser(77777777777777777, EPersonaState.Offline)>`
Since it online. Help me, please.

Comment: I can reproduce. Like you I'll get only Offline, even when querying _other_ users which I know are online. I'd suggest to post on github in issues.

Comment: Just to be sure, you do manage to query things like `name`, `last_logon()`, `get_avatar_url()`, right?

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle everything works fins, last_logon(), name and other stuff

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the steamid `77777777777777777` does not exist!

Steam stores their internal ids as a number that is incremental, the first user is 1, the second is 2, and repeating.

SteamID64 is the most common way steam represent users though. SteamID64 is also incremental, however the offset is at `76561197960265728` (0 in internal), so the first user would be `76561197960265728 + 1 = 76561197960265729`.

As you might see, `77777777777777777 - 76561197960265728 = 1216579817512049` is an enormous number, and that would be approximately 160532 times the world population.

If you link the Steam user you are trying to message in the comments, I can help you get the real SteamID64 :)

Comment: I'd think that OP obfuscated his steam_id, the same way he did for username and password ..

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle ooops, I did not realize that, but without knowing what steam_id it's about, I can't really help.

Comment: as @HuguesFontenelle said, yeah i obfuscated my steam_id. And i use SteamID64 to get user's state. But i still get "Offline" every time.